# std::ostream : class is inaccesible [C++]

Tags: c++, c++11, inner-classes, friend, ostream

I am getting this error in my implementation:

> struct bookdatabase::Bookdatabase::Book
>
> class "bookdatabase::BookDatabase::Book" is inaccessible

None of the following solutions solved my problem:

- [std::basic_ostream is inaccessible in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089332/stdbasic-ostream-is-inaccessible-in-c)
- [cannot access private members in friend ostream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371860/cannot-access-private-members-in-friend-ostream)
- [My ostream and istream friend function can't access private class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785411/my-ostream-and-istream-friend-function-cant-access-private-class-members)
- [member of class inaccessible](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/76214/)
- [Inaccessible Members ?](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/240533-inaccessible-members/)

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk4tR.png) a picture of what visual studio has issue with in the .cpp file.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR86S.png) a picture of the declaration in the header file.

## Database.h

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>


#ifndef BOOKDATABASE_H
#define BOOKDATABASE_H

namespace bookdatabase {
    class BookDatabase {
    private:
        struct Book {
        private:
            std::string authorFirstName, authorLastName, authorFullName, bookTitle, pubDate;
        public:
            Book(const std::string &authFirst, const std::string &authLast, const std::string &title, const std::string &date);
            std::string getAuthor() const;
            std::string getBookTitle() const;
            std::string getPubDate() const;
            bool operator < (const Book &rhs) const;
            friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const bookdatabase::BookDatabase::Book& book);
        };
        void sortBooks();
        std::vector<Book>::iterator search(const std::string &title);
    public:
        BookDatabase();
        void printBookList();
        std::vector<Book> getDatabase() const;
        void removeBook(const std::string &title);

        void addBook(const std::string &authFirst, const std::string &authLast, const std::string &title, const std::string &date);
    private:
        std::vector<Book> database;
    };
}

#endif // BOOKDATABASE_H
```

## Database.cpp

```
std::ostream & bookdatabase::operator<<(std::ostream & out, const bookdatabase::BookDatabase::Book & book) {
    out << authorFullName << ". " << bookTitle << ". " << pubDate;
    return out;
}
```

Am I having this issue because the `Book` class is a nested class?

Comment: _"Am I having this issue because the `Book` class is a nested class?"_ No, you have that issue because it is a **`private`** nested class.

Comment: @user0042 Thank you. It was my understanding that if the overloading operator is a friend of the class, it will have access to its private members. Does this not apply if the class is private? Does it make sense to make the operator a friend of the Database class instead to access the Book class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I seem to have discovered two things here which might be the problem you're having, one of which might be a bug in Visual Studio.

### 1. First of all, the thing which is not a bug

user0042, in his response to your post is right, `operator<<` being declared as `friend` in the `struct Book` results in the `operator<<` only being able to access private members of `Book`. But it cannot access `Book` itself, because `Book` is a private member of the enclosing `BookDatabase` class. Therefore you have to move the friend declaration to be outside `Book` and in `BookDatabase`.

Once you do that, `operator<<` can now access the private data member `Book` of `BookDatabase`. Note however that this does not give permission to `operator<<` to access the private data members of `Book` itself, namely `authorFirstName, authorLastName, authorFullName, bookTitle, pubDate`

### 2A. Now for the (what I believe to be) VS2017 scope operator bug

Let's say you have moved the friend declaration to `BookDatabase`, you still have to define the implementation in a specific way. The following two pieces of code should be equivalent ways to define the function in a `Database.cpp` file, *but one of them doesn't work in VS2017 15.4.5*.

**It's ok to do**

```
namespace bookdatabase {
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const bookdatabase::BookDatabase::Book& book) {
    }
}  // OK
```

**But not ok to do**

```
ostream& bookdatabase::operator<<(ostream& out, const bookdatabase::BookDatabase::Book& book) {
}  // Visual Studio cannot access book
```

There seems to be an issue with Visual Studio's `::` operator being able to obtain the `friend` property of a function.

***So to answer your question: if you want your << operator overload to work you need to use the first method to define it in the .cpp implementation file.***

### 2B. In fact I wrote a simple test program to show the VS2017 `friend` and `::` bug

```
namespace my_namespace {
    class Test {
    private:
        struct Nested {};
    public:
        friend void func(Test::Nested&);
    };
    void func(Test::Nested&);
}

// DOES NOT COMPILE in VS2017 15.4.5, OK in GCC 6.3 and Clang 3.8.0
// VS2017 says Nested is inaccessible
void my_namespace::func(my_namespace::Test::Nested&) {
}
```

But using `namespace` and brackets works

```
namespace my_namespace {
    class Test {
    private:
        struct Nested {};
    public:
        friend void func(Test::Nested&);
    };
    void func(Test::Nested&);
}

// changed to namespace + brackets, 
// COMPILES in VS2017 15.4.5, GCC 6.3 and Clang 3.8.0
namespace my_namespace {
    void func(my_namespace::Test::Nested&) {
    } 
}
```

Can someone please independently verify this?

I also posted a [bug report on the Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/159387/namespace-operator-bug-when-defining-a-friend-func.html)

Comment: I moved the `operator<<` friend function to the Database class and removed the `bookdatabase` namespace scope resolution operator, opting to put the `operator<<` implementation within a namespace block instead (as shown in your post). Unfortunately, I still receive the error that the nested `Book` class is inaccessible. I think the only solution may be to make the nested `Book` class public.

Comment: That's strange, does yours compile fine? Mine compiles fine. Can you show me what has gone wrong? 

If you're trying to access the data members of `Book` from within the function body then you can't do that because the `operator<<` is not a friend of the Book struct.

Answer (score 0):

My answer for most operator << woes is to declare a member print() method that does the hard work and call it from operator <<. 
Usually I am happy for the print method to be public, and get rid of all the friend nastiness.